# Linux - Nic's flags configuration

Tags: linux, network-programming, initialization, flags, nic

#### Context

Debian 64 bit. kernel 3.18.x

Litterally struggling to understand how a network driver is initialized.

I mean how to choose which flag to set. I dig in the kernel for days now to train myself. The card setup is the only point I miss.

I take the intel 82574 as an example. I downloaded the card's datasheet, saw many information but not a clue on how to setup the hardware.

#### Question

**Where to start** to know what flags to set ? The datasheet didn't helped me (i am not very experienced but willing to learn).

Please give me **a starting point, a tip or anything** to help me understand what is going on in the already written open sourced driver.

How can a developer knows how to initialize his nic ? (**yes reinventing the wheel the time to understand**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to read the source code of the kernel module that handles your specific NIC.

EDIT: Of course, to develop such a module, you'd usually just use a register map as specified in a data sheet or application node; often, manufacturers develop their linux drivers themselves, so the driver developers might even be the same people that developed the chipset (because it's really handy to have a platform to test against -- it's impossible to test hardware without having something *like* a driver, so you might as well write a proper driver).

Furthermore, devices often come with code examples -- no one is going to build a device based on an IC that he has not seen in action.

If you've got access to neither proper documentation nor source, you can only reverse engineer - and that's an incredibly large field.

Comment: Updated the question with the point I already did this. And how did the writer know about those details ?

Comment: a) He probably works for the manufacturer or/and b) he has access to data sheets?

Comment: @Larry: Is my answer better now?

Comment: Now you definitely enlighten me. Thanks Marcus

Comment: Few days later, I polish my network devices. I got it :) Thanks again Marcus

Answer (score 0):

Using your example with the Intel 82574 Network Adapter, Intel provides a zip file of the source code used to build the Linux driver. The driver is like all drivers in that it hooks into the OS API for Networking.

The Linux networking API is document on both the linux.org site and discussed on popular Linux sites like lwn.org. Below is the link to lwn's chapter on Network drivers using the networking API called NAPI.

https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch17.pdf

You'll notice in the Intel igb driver source code that the NAPI net_device data structure is one of the first things that is setup. It registers the driver with the OS. This way the OS knows which igb functions to call when loading/unloading the driver, or when needing to send/receive data.

The igb functions read/modify/write the necessary bits in the 82574's memory-mapped registers that control and monitor the device. The device registers are all documented in the 82574 datasheet available on Intel's site. And this is usually the case for almost any networking company like Broadcom/Chelsio/Mellanox/Marvell.

Hope that helps a little more.